# MS-Access Change Command Line Argument vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am opening a database with a shortcut that contains a /cmd argument.  It will load the startup form (A login screen) and check for the command line argument.  If it is set it will move it to a different form.  On that different form is a log-in button.  When you click that button, you go back to the login screen.  However, the log-in screen looks for the command line argument and goes straight back to the previous form.  A never ending loop.  So, what I want to do is programatically change the command line argument.  I have tried to set it to nothing, null, "", 0... nothing seems to work.

What can I do to change the argument once it has been passed?

Comment: @Fionnuala I have a start up form, but sometimes I want it to start with a different form, so I use the command line argument.  It works just like I want it to, when trying to go to the regular startup form... it still has the command argument set so it continues to go to the secondary form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't alter the `/CMD` argument after the Access session has started.  But I don't think you should need to.

Just make sure you evaluate `/CMD` only one time at the start of the Access session.  You can do that by moving the startup logic from your form into a custom function and calling that function from an *AutoExec* macro.

```vb
Public Function StartUp()
    If Len(Command) > 0 Then
        ' the VBA Command() function returns the command 
        ' line /CMD argument text;
        ' assume it is a form which should be opened instead of frmStart
        DoCmd.OpenForm Command
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmStart"
    End If
End Function
```

Consider refining that code to ensure the text returned by `Command()` refers to a form which actually exists in your db.

Then use the `RunCode` action of the *AutoExec* macro to call `StartUp()`:

[image: AutoExec macro with RunCode action calling custom function]

Finally, set the database's *Display Form* property to *(none)*.